How can scheduled Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications in React Native App?
Inside the Firebase Console, under the Cloud Messaging view, users are able to create test notifications. This functionality also allows you to schedule the time at which the notification will send to a device or set of devices.
Is it possible to create and send scheduled FCM notifications to specific devices by using firebase cloud functions and the Firebase Admin SDK? Is there an alternative way to solving this?
The current way that I send scheduled messages to users is like so:
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

// Bildirim için izin alma fonksiyonu
export async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled = 
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
}

// Kullanıcıdan bildirim için zaman al ve backend'e gönder
export async function scheduleNotification(hour, minute) {
  // Kullanıcının Firebase FCM Token'ını al
  const token = await messaging().getToken();
  const now = new Date();  // Şu anki zamanı al

  const futureTime = new Date(now.getTime() + (hour * 60 + minute) * 60000);

  // Backend API'ye isteği gönder
  fetch('https://us-central1-firebase-mommy-notificationer.cloudfunctions.net/scheduleNotification', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      token: token,
      time: futureTime, // Kullanıcının ayarladığı süre
      message: "Breastfeeding Time!", // Göndermek istediğiniz bildirim mesajı

    }),
  })
    .then(response => {
      Alert.alert('Bildirim Zamanlandı', `'Bildirim başarıyla zamanlandı.' ${response.json()}`);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error scheduling notification:', error);
    });

}

Is it possible to tap into the scheduling functionality of firebase cloud messaging outside of the firebase console? Or am I stuck with hacking my way around this issue?

There is no API in FCM to schedule message sending. You'll have to implement your own scheduling mechanism, or use another (add-on) service that allows this use-case through its API (use search to find those).

This is the way without firebase https://github.com/musawarbilal786/Alarm-APP-with-React-Native/blob/main/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
